# org.apache.jasper.JasperException:

Tags: jsp, struts2

In my jsp page

```
       <s:if test="#alist[0].aboutme!=null"  test="#alist[0].aboutme!=''">
         <div class="info">
            <div class="title">
               About
            </div>
            <div class="value">
               <div class="value_title">
                    <s:property value="alist[0].aboutme"/>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </s:if>
```

I am checking ArrayList alist[0] about me value if it is null or '' 
It will not show aboutme text and value
previously it was working properly but now it is showing following  Exception

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/profile/about.jsp (line: 67, column: 102)   Attribute qualified names must be unique within an element
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:171)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:153)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1236)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1452)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `test` attributes in the `s:if` tag:

```
<s:if test="#alist[0].aboutme!=null"  test="#alist[0].aboutme!=''">
```

Try this:

```
<s:if test="%{#alist[0].aboutme!=null and #alist[0].aboutme!=''}">
```

Comment: Maybe it's `&&` instead of `and`. I get easily confused... Could you try with `&&`? If this works, I'd edit my answer. But as @kaliatech wrote, it's wrong to have two `test` attributes in the same `s:if` element.

Comment: both are not working. I dont think that it wont allow logical operators

Comment: Did a quick search over my code, found some `s:if` with boolean operators `<s:if test="%{#request.firstRange!=-1 or #request.previousRange!=-1 or #request.nextRange!=-1 or #request.lastRange!=-1}">`. I'm editing my answer with the `%{...}` syntax.

Comment: <s:if test="alist[0].aboutme!=null and alist[0].aboutme!=''}">  this is working Thanks @orique

Answer (score 0):

Your first line contains this:

```
<s:if test="#alist[0].aboutme!=null"  test="#alist[0].aboutme!=''">
```

You can not have two `test` attributes for a single `if` element